# create an array such that it contains elements from 0 to N in binary

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I need a fast algorithm which will generate all possible numbers upto a given number N in binary into an array.

```
e.g N=3
Then the array should be {0,0,0},{0,0,1}.....{1,1,1}
N<=17.
```

I have tried this so far which is a recursive solution.

```
void print_digits(int n, std::string const& prefix = "") {
    if (!n) {
        printf("%s,",prefix.c_str());
        return;
    }
    print_digits(n-1, prefix + '0');
    print_digits(n-1, prefix + '1');
}
```

i need a better algorithm.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you try writing some code yourself then post more specific questions

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<n; i++) a[i] = i;`

Comment: What's you definition of fast?  If N<=17, you would need a char array of size 17*2^17, so it's only 119KiB and you can easily build it at compile time.

Comment: i do not understand why are there 3 downvotes for this question...i feel the question is well explained and i have even provided my code which means i did try it before asking??...somebody please explain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the integers in C++ are stored directly in memory as their binary representation. Thus, if you just want to store N numbers, you should just write them directly into an array "as-is"

```
std::vector<unsigned> Numbers;
// if N is length of the number, calculate the maximum as 2^N - 1
long long Max = 1 << N - 1;
for (unsinged i = 0; i < Max; ++i)
    Numbers.push_back(i);
```

If you want to write them in the binary representation, it's also pretty straightforward, even if you want to code it all by yourself. (*Please excuse me, as this is just an simple example implementation*)

```
void PrintAsBits(unsigned value) {
    for (int i = sizeof(unsigned) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        cout << ((1 << i) & value) ? 1 : 0;
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone cares anymore, the following code implements the original spec, which calls for a way to populate a 2-dimensional array where each value is represented as a numeric array whose elements correspond to its value's binary digits, in big-endian order.

```
#include <iostream>

static const int DIGIT_COUNT = 10;

static const int VALUE_COUNT = 1 << DIGIT_COUNT;
unsigned char g_binarray[VALUE_COUNT][DIGIT_COUNT];

void Populate() {
    for(int i=0; i<VALUE_COUNT; ++i) {
        unsigned char (&curr)[DIGIT_COUNT] = g_binarray[i];
        for(int di=0; di<DIGIT_COUNT; ++di) {
            curr[di] = unsigned char((i >> (DIGIT_COUNT - 1 - di)) & 1);
        }
    }
}

void DumpArray() {
    static const char *digits = "01";
    for(int i=1; i<VALUE_COUNT; ++i) {
        for(int di=0; di<DIGIT_COUNT; ++di) {
            std::cout << digits[!!g_binarray[i][di]];
        }
        std::cout << "    " << i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Populate();
    DumpArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I wrote in 1 post:

Example: If you need of length 4, then you must have 2^4 = 16 different arrays.

You can use this simple Java code to generate all arrays:

```
for (int i=0; i < 16; i++) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
```

The output of this:

> 0 1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111

Comment: Isn't the question tagged algorithm?